# Best way to schedule tasks on dates

Tags: django, django-models

Consider a scenario where I have the following:
 - Users 
 - Powers 
 - Eligible

In my `Power` model, I gave the superuser the ability to create custom powers and among those options to create the power, there's a field where the they can choose an eligibility date for when those powers are available to the `User` and 'amount' how many times can they used in a month. That's fairly simple, but, I also have an other model called `Eligible` which looks like this:

```py
class Eligible(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=blahblah)
    power = models.ForeignKey(Power)
    eligible = models.BooleanField()
    balance = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
```

When I create a User, link the Power to that user object, if they're immediately eligible, that User's object for the Power in the `Eligible` model is created and the `eligible` field is set to true and the amount is added to their balance, if they're not eligible, it's set to false and then I want to create a task that automatically updates their balance every month.

- Schedule a task for every object for a date?
- Run a task every 24 hours that iterates over all the un-eligible Users and make's them eligible if the date is of the eligibility date?

If so, how do I do either of those?

Thank you for your time. I tried my best to write this how a sober person would.

Comment: So your power contains an `elegible_date`? If that is true, you can simply implement a checking mechanism that checks if the current timestamp is within range. No need to schedule tasks at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't. You can simply write some logic that makes a *check* if the current tiemstamp is later than that timestamp.

For example if the `Power` model looks like:

```
class Power(models.Model):
    activate = models.DateTimeField()
```

Then we can implement logic like:

```
from django.utils.timezone import now

class Eligible(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=…)
    power = models.ForeignKey(Power, on_delet=…)
    immediately_eligible = models.BooleanField()

    @property
    def is_eligible(self):
        return self.immediately_eligible or now() >= self.power.activate
```

So the `is_eligible` property will be `True`, if `immediately_eligible` is set to `True`, or the timestamp is later than (or equal to) the `self.power.activate`.